# Image not in all the screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a web page and I want to display many images in a slideshow. I succeeded to switch the images but the problem is that the images don't take all the screen.
For my example, I took two same size images on a website.

This is my result :

[images not in all the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycc1E.jpg)

This is my code:

```css
.slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid #F2F2F2;
}

.slideshow ul {
  /* 4 images donc 4 x 100% */
  width: 400%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.slideshow li {
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-style: none;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="./assets/image/img1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="./assets/image/img2.jpg" alt="" width="350" /></li>
    <li><img src="./assets/image/img1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="./assets/image/img2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can u plz add this in codepen or fiddle? Image does not open..

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Comment: It's possible to add img and jquery script with fiddle ??

Comment: set `width: 100vmax;` style for `<img>` tag

Comment: @KuRuVI yes for both. For Jquery you have the option and for images specify a src using a url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap component named "Carousel" to add slideshow in your web page. You can add this component to your code and add as many images as you want in your web page. All of them will be in one size. 
I am adding Bootstrap link here: This will surely help you.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/

Comment: Thank you ! I succeeded with Bootstrap. But do you know how can I change the time paused in a image ?

Comment: Yes! You can add Source files of Bootstrap in your <head> by downloading them from here:      https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/          By adding these files, you can reach the classes that are used in construction of Bootstrap Carousel.Find the class for slideshow time in those source files of bootstrap and edit  there.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a vague question, the problem here is the size of your image more than likely, but you might try adding `width: 100vw;` and/or `height: 100vh;` to your `img` CSS declaration.

**Note:** these are just suggestions, you may not like the behavior of the viewport, not everyone does. It works for a lot of my needs.

It would look like this:

```
img {
    width: 100vw;
    display: block;
    border-style: none;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: inherit;
 }
```

This will not work in some older browsers, but here are a couple articles that might help you out:

https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

https://tipue.com/blog/css3-vw-vh/